# Apply with LinkedIn. GET profile using profile ID

Tags: linkedin-api

The goal of my aplication is to get profile of any linkedin user with "Apply with LinkedIn".
I've registered in Apply with LinkedIn, got clientId, client secret, and performend oauth2 authentification successfuly.
But with linkedIn api I can get only info about my LinkedIn profile:
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,skills,educations,languages,twitter-accounts)?format=json

Does anybody know is it possible to GET other profile (not mine) using profileID, linkedinId or somewhat else?

Thanks,
Tatyana.

Comment: I doesn't find any doc related to fetch data from other's rather than opening others profile.

Comment: According to Linkedin documentation [link] (https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/apply-with-linkedin) I can get only my profile.

Comment: we can open others profile :)

Comment: We can open other profile in a browser, but it is not possible to specify profileID, linkedIn Id or something else using GET https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,skills,educations,languages,twitter-accounts)?format=json

Answer (score 0):

You need to use people search API with "r_network" permission, which is a vetted API access program now.

https://developer-programs.linkedin.com/documents/people-search-api

You can apply here https://help.linkedin.com/app/ask/path/api-dvr for the same.

Please make sure that your app follows the following guidelines from Linkedin before submitting for review

- It may not be used for the purposes of database matching, candidate
  sourcing, or lead generation without an established business
  relationship with LinkedIn.
- You can never store data returned from the People Search API.
- Search results may not be stored or offered as aggregated search.
- All APIcalls must be made within an active user session.
- You cannot let multiple people search using the authentication credentials of one person. Each person must authenticate individually.

HTH

Comment: According to responce from LinkedIn they do not support people search anymore.
"Hi Татьяна,
 
Due to changes in the API program we no longer offer people search outside of the Partner Program. You can review the changes here: https://developer.linkedin.com/.
 
Regards,
 
Apply with LinkedIn Review Team
LinkedIn"

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of ways to do it.
If you have the account's ID (as retrieved from another API call -- not the ID you see in the standard URL).

`/v1/people/id=xxxx:(your fields go here)`

Or if you have the public URL of their linkedin account (URL Encoded!)

`/v1/people/url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.linkedin.com%2Fin%2Fsome-account-name`

Note: I have found that the values returned are quite limited, even for a 1st degree connection when authenticated with scope=r_fullprofile. It returns only the current positions for example, no skills, no education, amoung other things.  It's really of limited use.

It's not clear why.

Comment: Tried /v1/people/url=... it is OK, but the response contains only id, first-name, last-name, headline. 
Unfortunately this info isn't enought.

Comment: The API Doc specifies that access to any user other than the authenticated one is limited to the "3rd degree connection" info... this is the case even if the profile is a 1st degree connection of the authenticated user.